# How to replace a string that contains a specific character in python?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to use python to go through a text file and replace all strings that contain the substring "e-" with "0.0".

For example, in the line:

0.46790 0.25440 3.5637e-0 0.0082447 0.0016506 0.00018180 -99 0.0010338 0.00067166 0.0043598

"3.5637e-0" would be replaced by 0.0.  The numbers surrounding "e-" will not necessarily be the same for each occurrence.

If possible, I would like to modify the following code (where "- " gets replaced by "-99 ") to do this, but I am open to other suggestions, as well:

```
with open(outputfile, "wt") as fout:
    with open(datafile, "rt") as fin:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace('- ', '-99 '))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd split the line, replace any element that contains "e-" with "0.0" and rejoin it:

```
fout.write(' '.join(['0.0' if 'e-' in x else x for x in line.split(' ')]))
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the regular expressions module in a manner similar to:

```
import re
import sys

def process_file(src, dst=sys.stdout):
    for line in src:
        dst.write(re.sub("\d+\.\d+e\-\d+", "0.0", line))

def main(paths):
    for path in paths:
        with open(path, "rb") as fp:
            process_file(fp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

If I create a file with the following contents

```
0.46790 0.25440 3.5637e-0 0.0082447 0.0016506 0.00018180 -99 0.0010338 0.00067166 0.0043598
0.46790 0.25440 3.5637e-0 0.0082447 0.0016506 0.00018180 -99 0.0010338 0.00067166 0.0043598
```

and run the program (called `example.py`) as follows

```
$ python example.py test.txt test.txt
```

I get the following output

```
0.46790 0.25440 0.0 0.0082447 0.0016506 0.00018180 -99 0.0010338 0.00067166 0.0043598
0.46790 0.25440 0.0 0.0082447 0.0016506 0.00018180 -99 0.0010338 0.00067166 0.0043598

0.46790 0.25440 0.0 0.0082447 0.0016506 0.00018180 -99 0.0010338 0.00067166 0.0043598
0.46790 0.25440 0.0 0.0082447 0.0016506 0.00018180 -99 0.0010338 0.00067166 0.0043598
```

You could adapt the program to fit your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following two lines before your last one.

```
contents = [x.replace("e-", '0.0') for x in line.split()]
fout.write(' '.join(contents) + '\n')
```

What this does is that it splits `line` whenever a space is met and applied the `replace` method in every piece. Here we are taking advantage of the fact that `replace` also works even if the sub-string we are looking for is not in the string to begin with. After modifying the line, we stitch it back together, append a linefeed and write it to file.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/R2gEyu/1), though it may be overkill in this instance.

```
import re

fout.write(re.sub(r"[\d.]+e-\d+", "0.0", line))
```